# send messages to a rfcomm terminal?

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I created a connection through bluetooth between a client using a gumstix and a server on linux.
This is what I did with the server:

```
ftph-user@ftph-9818:~$ hcitool dev
Devices:
hci0    B0:10:41:BA:BF:26
ftph-user@ftph-9818:~$ rfcomm watch /dev/rfcomm0 3 /sbin/agetty rfcomm0 115200 linux

Waiting for connection on channel 3
Connection from 00:03:19:50:2A:FB to /dev/rfcomm0
Press CTRL-C for hangup
```

On the client:

```
root@ftph-9817-gbt:~$ rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 B0:10:41:BA:BF:26 3
Connected /dev/rfcomm0 to B0:10:41:BA:BF:26 on channel 3
Press CTRL-C for hangup
```

>

What I would like is to be able to type on client  and read on server, execute some scripts too, instead all I have is a blank screen.

Any idea?

Best regards,
Leo

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to connect using a virtual (bluetooth) COM port from Windows to Linux and send data from the windows machine to the Linux machine. In order to do this, I set up a virtual COM port on Windows after pairing/connecting to the Bluetooth adaptor on Linux. Then, I used the following command:

```
    sudo rfcomm watch /dev/rfcomm0 <chan> screen /dev/rfcomm0 115200
```

In your case chan is 3.

You can install screen using `apt-get install screen`.

Then on Windows, I connected to the outgoing virtual COM port that is tied to the Linux machine. This launches the screen serial port console on the Linux machine. I was then able to type on the Windows Serial Port program and see the chars reflected on the Screen console on Linux.